# Monobehaviour script method does not appear as an option for UI button's On Click

Tags: unity, c#, gui, unity-ui

I have the following script, and when I try to use a UI button to call the `CheckGuess` method,  it does not appear as an option:

[image: My script configured on my Game controller object]

[image: The button On Click() event showing no option to select CheckGuess]

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class Guessthenumbergame: MonoBehaviour   
{
    public InputField input;

    public Text infoText;

    private int guessNumber;

    private int userGuess;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        guessNumber = Random.Range(0, 100);

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    public void CheckGuess()
    {
        userGuess = int.Parse(input.text);
        if (userGuess == guessNumber)
        {
            infoText.text = "You guessed the number right";
        }else if (userGuess > guessNumber)
        {
            infoText.text = "Your number is higher";
        }else if (userGuess < guessNumber)
        {
            infoText.text = "Your number is lower";
        }
        input.text = "";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code as shown here does not compile.

Because you have both `using System;` and `using UnityEngine;`, the compiler doesn't know whether this line:

```
guessNumber = Random.Range(0, 100);
```

...wants to use the version of `Random` in the `System` namespace, or the one in the `UnityEngine` namespace.

So my guess is that the reason your function isn't showing up is because your code has not successfully compiled since you added it.

Make sure you're in the habit of checking the Console window in Unity and resolving any errors it tells you about. As long as there's a compiler error, the versions of your scripts you see in the editor will be stuck at the last version that successfully compiled.

When I disambiguate the reference by removing the `using System;` directive, or qualifying the reference as `guessNumber = UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, 100);`, the code compiles, and the `CheckGuess()` method appears as an option for the button's `On Click()`